# Demonstration of Simple harmonic motion and Hooke's law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, harmonic-oscillator, spring

Im very new physic student. Im studying this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNpuTx7UQbw&index=11&list=PLyQSN7X0ro203puVhQsmCj9qhlFQ-As8e it's about Simple harmonic motion and hooke's law. the professor explains about the theory that if we have experimentation on a frictionless surface and we got a spring attached to the wall on the left side then at the end of the other side of the spring (right side) we attach it to the object (i call the object at the relax range of the spring is x=0). then we pull the object to the right side making the spring exceeds its relax range (x= positive number) but still obeys hooke's law then we let the object go. there will be an infinite oscillation of the object back and forth centred around the position x=0 and the function of that position compared to time T has a sinusoid shape.

My question is: this theory talks about the 1 spring which left side attach to the wall and the right side attach to the object but when professor in the video make demonstration in the minute 26:44 i see the object which has 2 holes, one on the left and one on the right placed on the centre of the air track (very little friction surface) but there are 2 springs one is attached on the left end of the machine to the left hole of the object, the other one is attach to the right end of the machine to the right hole of the object. why when the professor explain his theory he talks about one spring attach to the object but when he make demonstration he use 2 spring attach to both side of the object? is his theory still valid?

if we consider in the hooke's law the object only get force from one spring not 2. How the 2 spring system works???? I'm very very confuse what he is doing. can you please explain to me very step by step detail for beginner. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The theory is valid also for two springs. Assume there are walls at $x=0$ and $x=L$, and the mass $m$ is connected to them using springs of constant $k$ and length $\frac{L}{2}$ when relaxed. Lets denote by $x$ the position of the mass $m$. Then the length of the left spring is $x$ and the length of the right one is $L-x$. Therefore, by Hooke's law

$$\Sigma F=-k\left(x-\frac{L}{2}\right)+k\left(L-x-\frac{L}{2}\right)=-2k\left(x-\frac{L}{2}\right)$$

which means that two springs of constant $k$ (in parallel) are equivalent to one spring of constant $2k$, and in particular the motion is still harmonic.